# Replace diagonal elements in sparse matrix

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, replacement, sparse-arrays

I am interested in replacing all elements in a diagonal of a sparse matrix with zero. Currently, I do it in the following manner:

```
spA = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 3, {1, 3} -> 4}]
withOutDiagonalELements = DeleteCases[ArrayRules[spA], {a_, a_} -> _];
spAwd =  SparseArray@Append[withOutDiagonalELements, {_, _} -> 0.0];
```

Any suggestions on how to do it more efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
removeDiagonal = 
  # SparseArray[SparseArray`SparseArrayRemoveDiagonal[#]["NonzeroPositions"] -> 1, 
   Dimensions[#]] &;

removeDiagonal[spA]
```

> SparseArray[<4>,{3,3}]

```
removeDiagonal[spA] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & 0 & 4 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
removeDiagonal[spA]["NonzeroPositions"]
```

> {{1,3}}

**Some timings:**

```
f1 = removeDiagonal;
f2 = SparseArray[# - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[#, 0], 0,  
      Dimensions[#]]] &; (* Henrik Shumacher *)
f3 = With[{zeros = 1 - IdentityMatrix[Dimensions@#, SparseArray]}, #*
     zeros] &; (* Mr. Wizard *)
f4 = ReplacePart[#, {i_, i_} :> 0] &; (* tomd *)

m1 = SparseArray[Tuples[RandomSample[Range[101], 100], {2}] -> 1, {101, 101}];
m2 = SparseArray[Tuples[RandomSample[Range[100000], 100], {2}] -> 1, {100000, 100000}];

m = m1;
t11 = First[RepeatedTiming[r11 = f1 @ m ;]];
t21 = First[RepeatedTiming[r21 = f2 @ m;]];
t31 = First[RepeatedTiming[ r31 = f3 @ m;]];
t41 = First[RepeatedTiming[ r41 = f4 @ m;]];
r11 == r21 == r31 == r41
```

> True

```
m = m2;
t12 = First[RepeatedTiming[r12 = f1 @ m ;]];
t22 = First[RepeatedTiming[r22 = f2 @ m;]];
t32 = First[RepeatedTiming[ r32 = f3 @ m;]];
t42 = "n/a"; (* b/c computation exceeded the limitation of free plan on  Wolfram Cloud *)
r12 == r22 == r32
```

> True

```
{{"dimensions", "non-zero elements", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"},
 {{101, 101}, 100, t11, t21, t31, t41}, 
 {{100000, 100000}, 100, t12, t22, t32, t42}} // Grid[#, Dividers -> All] &  // TeXForm
```

> $\small\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{dimensions} & \text{non-zero elements} & \text{f1} & \text{f2} & \text{f3} & \text{f4} \\
> \hline
>  \{101,101\} & 100 & 0.000322 & 0.000279 & 0.000131 & 0.00487 \\
> \hline
>  \{100000,100000\} & 100 & 0.0017 & 0.0053 & 0.004 & \text{n/a} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

Comment: I don't believe I've seen `SparseArrayRemoveDiagonal` before.  Have you been using it or did you discover it only now?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I bumped into it some time ago. This is probably the second time I have used it.

Answer (score 9):

You can multiply a binary matrix by your Sparse Array, and that matrix may itself be a [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html).

```
spA = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 3, {1, 3} -> 4}];

zeros = 1 - IdentityMatrix[Dimensions @ spA, SparseArray];

spA*zeros // Grid
```

> $\begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & 0 & 4 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}$

See also [`Band`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html) and [`DiagonalMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiagonalMatrix.html) for other tools to construct the zeros array.

Answer (score 7):

Just subtract the diagonal matrix:

```
SparseArray[spA - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[spA]]]
```

As Mr. Wizard pointed out, if `spA` is not a square matrix, one can use

```
k = 0;
SparseArray[spA - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[spA, k], k, Dimensions[spA]]]
```

Here, `k` stands for the number of the diagonal you what to delete. `k = 0` stands for the main diagonal, `k = 1` for the first diagonal *above* the main diagonal, `k = -1` for the first diagonal below the main diagonal etc.

Comment: I think the `SparseArray` wrapper is superfluous.

Comment: Yes and no. Wrapping with `SparseArray` removes the diagonal entries from the list of `"NonzeroPositions". There are both reasons for and against this...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You mean nonsquare matrices? Good point! Fixed it.

Comment: Sorry, yes of course I meant non-square.  You already had my +1.

Answer (score 3):

Two methods to add a list to the diagonal of a sparse matrix are given as below. The performance varies greatly.

```
n = 100000;
a = RandomReal[1, n];
Ksp = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} :> a[[i]]}, Length[a]];
Ksp2 = Ksp;
```

**Method 1**

```
t1 = Timing[Do[Ksp[[i, i]] += a[[i]], {i, Length[a]}]][[1]]
```

> 33.7742

**Method 2**

```
t2 = Timing[Ksp2 += SparseArray[{{i_, i_} :> a[[i]]}, Length[a]]][[1]]
```

> 0.0312002

*Compare:*

```
t1/t2
```

> 1082.5

Answer (score 2):

```
ReplacePart[spA, {i_, i_} :> 0]
```

and

```
Diagonal[ReplacePart[spA, {i_, i_} :> 0]] // Normal
```

> {0, 0, 0}

In general:

```
ReplacePart[spA, {i_, i_} :> {a, b, c}[[i]]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this can be very slow.