# Diagonal matrix command in Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sparse-arrays, matlab

How to find the corresponding Mathematica commands for ***diagonal matrix*** operation in *Matlab*, e.g.

```
 AA=rand(3,3);
```

**Step 1.)** finding the diagonal elements, and export them as a list "tmp"

```
tmp = spdiags(AA,0);
```

**Step 2.)** modifying one list element

```
tmp(2)=1;
```

**Step 3.)** return the changed diagonal elements in matrix  backmat

```
backmat=spdiags(tmp,0,AA); % reinsert diagonal;
```

How can we define the **Step 1** & **Step 3** in Mathematica 12.2?

Comment: Can you, please, describe what each step is doing here? It is not clear what is being done in these steps.

Comment: @CATrevillian just check now! simple test!

Comment: Use the concrete  example instead of MatLab code will make it easy to understand.

Comment: Please show us the desired input and output rather than MATLAB code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
AA=rand(3,3)
tmp = spdiags(AA,0)
tmp(2)=1
backmat=spdiags(tmp,0,AA);
full(backmat)
```

gives

```
AA =
    0.6948    0.0344    0.7655
    0.3171    0.4387    0.7952
    0.9502    0.3816    0.1869

tmp =
    0.6948
    0.4387
    0.1869

tmp =
    0.6948
    1.0000
    0.1869

ans =
    0.6948    0.0344    0.7655
    0.3171    1.0000    0.7952
    0.9502    0.3816    0.1869
```

In Mathematica

```
(AA = {{0.6948, 0.0344, 0.7655}, {0.3171, 0.4387, 0.7952}, {0.9502, 
    0.3816, 0.1869}}) // MatrixForm
tmp = Diagonal[AA, 0];
tmp[[2]] = 1;
backmat = 
 SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> tmp] + 
  SparseArray@UpperTriangularize[AA, 1] + 
  SparseArray@LowerTriangularize[AA, -1]
MatrixForm[backmat]
```

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not think Mathematica has command to insert diagonal into sparse matrix directly like Matlab's [spdiags](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html) but it is possible to do it as above indirectly.

Comment: NICE work! thanks! can we use other commands in MMA 12.2 ?

Comment: what is the meaning of Band[{1, 1}] in this case?

Comment: @a Then why not `AA[[2,2]]=1`?

Comment: @xzczd here, we use a very simple test case to understand this issue, the real case is that we need to modify  a very large sparse matrix using  "% reinsert diagonal;"...

Comment: @a Sparse matrix isn't a problem, `AA` in `AA[[2,2]]=1` can be a `SparseArray`.

Comment: @a If what you really need to do is to modify the whole diagonal matrix rather than one element of it, strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/178641/1871

Comment: @xzczd thanks for your suggestion!